# can a zfs disk be replaced with an imaged-copy [zol]

Tags: zfs

If I have a theoretical pool "tank" 500gb X 4 drives as devices vd{a,b,c,d}

could I pull vdc from the system, image it (bit-wise clone) onto another 500gb disk, and install the clone (lets call this fifth device vde) on the host, would I be able to import this pool normally?

I anticipate zfs may not like that the physical device changed, or may have some other "quirky" behaviors that might make trying to `zpool replace ...` more difficult than before.

---

with a clone of a raidz member,these things I've found don't work

- ```
  zpool export tank
  zpool import tank
  ```

  new device ignored
- ```
  zpool replace tank vdc /dev/vde
  ```

  > /dev/vde is part of active pool tank
- ```
  zpool online tank /dev/vde
  ```

  > cannot online /dev/vde no such device in pool
- ```
  zpool offline tank vdc
  zpool online tank /dev/vde
  ```

  > cannot online /dev/vde no such device in pool
- ```
  zpool attach tank vdc vde
  ```

  > /dev/vde is part of active pool cryo
- ```
  zpool online tank vde
  ```

  > cannot online vde: no such device in pool

Comment: maybe the reason this doesn't seem to come up is, this requires offline'ing the pool and most people prefer operating with uptime rather than quick maintenance operation.

Comment: Make sure the new physical device behaves like the old one, otherwise you might risk data losses. Easiest way is to use the same type of drive again. Or buy a new 2TByte (costs round about 50€ for consumer grade and round about 100€ for enterprise grade - i.E. 2 TByte Seagate Exos 200MByte/s Read/Write) drive and send your old disks into retirement.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic here. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please delete this and ask, instead, on [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 4):

### yes, by offlining the pool (export+import)

zpool import will find the new disk when the original disk is missing

Note: `zpool offline tank sdc`, before copying if possible, this helps reduce scrub time&wear. `zpool online task sde` after export+import. before export+import, while the device is offline, checksum the copies to ensure no copy defects.

```
  pool: tank
 state: ONLINE
  scan: resilvered 8K in 0h0m with 0 errors 
config:       
                                                         
        NAME         STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        tank         ONLINE       0     0     0
          raidz3-0   ONLINE       0     0     0
            sda      ONLINE       0     0     0
            sdb      ONLINE       0     0     0
            sdc      ONLINE       0     0     0
            sdd      ONLINE       0     0     0
```

- (safely) [disconnect the old device](https://superuser.com/questions/600731/ejecting-sata-device-in-linux) (export the pool first)

  ```
  # echo 1 >/sys/block/sdc/device/delete
  ```
- scan for pool

  ```
  # zpool import -d /dev/disk/by-id/

         pool: tank                                                                                                       
        state: ONLINE                                         
         scan: resilvered 8K in 0h0m with 0 errors
       config:                                                                    

               NAME         STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
               tank         ONLINE       0     0     0
                 raidz3-0   ONLINE       0     0     0
                   sda      ONLINE       0     0     0
                   sdb      ONLINE       0     0     0
                   sde      ONLINE       0     0     0  # clone detected
                   sdd      ONLINE       0     0     0
  ```
- import pool

  ```
  # zpool import -d /dev/disk/by-id/ tank
  ```
- scrub suggested, to ensure clone isn't missing any changes, or has any bad blocks

  ```
  zpool scrub tank
  ```